Prove that is a Markov chain from definition
I have $P(U_n = 1) = P(U_n = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. I have to check if $A_n = U_{n+1}U_n$ is a Markov chain. $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ are independent.
I wrote that $A_{n-1} = U_{n-1}U_{n}$ so it is dependent on $U_{n-1}$ which is not included in $A_n$, so $A_n$ is dependent on the future and not only on the previous state, so it is not a Markov chain. Is it correct?

please provide definition for more clarity in the answer. I am not sure what you are referring here as future either.

with future I mean we have n in X index and it is dependent on $U_{n+1}$ and I can't write it using recursion with $X_{n-1}$, sorry for writing it not clearly

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$ I'm assuming the $(U_n)$ are independent. Conditioning on the value of $U_{1}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\P(A_{n+1}=a_{n+1}|A_n=a_n,\dots, A_1=a_1) &= \P(U_{n+1}U_{n+2}=a_{n+1} | U_nU_{n+1} = a_n, \dots, U_1U_2=a_1) \\ 
&= \P(U_{n+2}=a_{n+1}U_{n+1} | U_{n+1}=a_nU_n, \dots, U_2 = a_1U_1) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \P(U_{n+2}=a_{n+1}\cdots a_1) + \frac{1}{2} \P(U_{n+2} = -a_{n+1}\cdots a_1) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} 
\end{align*}
while conditioning on the value of $U_{n+2}$ and noting $\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n} = \frac{U_{n+2}}{U_n}$, we find $\P(A_{n+1}=a_{n+1}|A_n=a_n) = \frac 12$. So the process is indeed a Markov chain.

But if they are dependent, then the analysis is wrong

@PavelFedotov The question specifies that the $(U_n)$ are independent. Can I ask where the downvotes come from?

How do we get $U_{n+2} = a_{n+1}U_{n+1}$? Did you write it that way, because $U_n$ can only be $1$ or $-1$?

No idea, I am absolutely downvoted here as well.

@jupyter51 Yes.

It does not say anything about probability distribution I guess
